# Android MediaPlayer stops on onBackPressed

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have lots of problems with `MediaPlayer`.
It's likely pertaining to old OS versions, at least until 2.3.

One sound is playing fine in a certain `Activity` (right before launching another)
When I pop the second `Activity` to go back to the first one, I play the sound file right before the popping (I use super.onBackPressed).

On these old devices (~2.3), the sound file is cut off.
I use the same way of launching and playing the `MediaPlayer`.

I create the `MediaPlayer` using `create` (synched). I retain the `MediaPlayer` by putting it in a static container. I released end empty the container only on `setOnCompletionListener`. What's going on..

Here's some code...

```
// Start sound
adhocplaysoundstatic(R.raw.soundfile, getApplicationContext()); 
// Pop activity
super.onBackPressed();
```

Definition

```
static ArrayList<MediaPlayer> staticplayers = new ArrayList<MediaPlayer>();
static public void adhocplaysoundstatic(final int MEDIA, Context context) {
    MediaPlayer player = getMediaPlayerStatic(MEDIA, context);
    staticplayers.add(player); // Hold on to
    player.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.release();
            staticplayers.remove(mp);
        }
    });
    player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onPrepared, play!");
            mp.start();             
        }});
    //player.start();
}
```

More...

```
static protected MediaPlayer getMediaPlayerStatic(int id, Context context) throws RuntimeException {
    MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(context, id);
    if (player == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed creating media player from id " + id);
    }
    else {
        player.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
            @Override public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MediaPlayer error: " + mp.toString() + ", what: " + what + ", extra: " + extra);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    return player;
}
```

Comment: I second @AndroidKiller 's request for code; in particular, I'd like to know how exactly your _static container_ (interesting phrase indicating a potential problem) is built.

Comment: Ok I will add code when I get some free time. Anyway sounds being cut off seems to be a pretty well known problem. I "solved" it by extending all sound effects physically by 0.5 second silence at the end. For this I used a program called "sox" that works at command line, allowing batch processing of lots of files. Workaround, but it worked well.

Comment: Added code. The OnPreparedListener really didn't change anything and should probably not be necessary since `MediaPlayer.create` is synchronized. I use local sound files. Tried both mp3 and ogg.